# How to add class attribute to form label generated by Zend Framework 2.

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, label

I'm trying to control certain elements like this in ZF2:

```
<label class="control-label">...</label>
```

I've tried to do so by using the following code in ZF2's form:

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'year',
            'type' => 'select',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'yearSelect',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Op welke datum wilt u arriveren?',
                'label_attributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'testFieldset',
                )
            )
        ));
```

But the css I'm assigning to the class **testFieldset** just won't work.
(the id attribute 'yearSelect' is assigned though, and can be used.)

If any other information is required, please ask, new to this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of ZF2 are you using? What you have done seems correct.

Comment: Are you rendering using the form element helpers? Specifically the [`Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormLabel`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper/FormLabel.php), `echo $this->formLabel($element)` in the view?